# How to use AutoMapper for mapping with nesting properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, nested, automapping

I have 2 tables [Customer] [Sale] and related with each others, I try to map Sale to SaleDto and show with customer name.

Customer Model

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Sale>? Sales { get; set; }
}
```

Sale Model

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }

    public Customer? Customer { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SaleOrder>? SaleOrders { get; set; }
```

SaleDto

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
```

I try to map the sale.customer.Name to SaleDto.CustomerName, but it didnt work for me.

AutoMapper

```
    public MappingProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<Sale, SaleDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerName,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Customer.Name));             
    }
```

API

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<Sale>))]
    public IActionResult GetSales()
    {
        var sales = _mapper.Map<List<SaleDto>>(_saleRepository.GetSales());

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        return Ok(sales);
    }
```

How ever I get the customerName with NULL, can someone help me with this?? I try to show the name of the customer

Response body

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "customerId": 1,
    "customerName": null,
    "amount": 2325,
    "created": "2023-07-10T22:25:49.3510244"
  }
]
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

AutoMapper supports [flattening](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html) so event this `ForMember` setup should not actually be needed. I'm pretty sure that the issue is in the repository which does not fetch needed inrofrmation. Be sure to use `Include` (i.e. `_context.Customer.Include(c => c.Sales)`) in the query or any other form of [loading related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/).

Also I highly recommend to look into using the AutoMapper's [Queryable Extensions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) with the `ProjectTo` method.

P.S.

Note that using Repository pattern on top of Entity Framework can be considered an antipattern, since EF is already a repository (read more - [Is the repository pattern useful with Entity Framework Core?](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-core/))